# There is a way to callThrough with jasmine.createSpyObj?

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How can I use callThrough with jasmine.createSpyObj and object with methods' returns?

the below example does not work.

```
const exampleSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ExampleSpy', {
        method1: () => Promise.resolve(true),
        method2: () => 'testResult'
});
exampleSpy.and.callThrough();

const res = exampleSpy.method2();
expect(res).toBe('testResult');
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `exampleSpy.method2.and.callThrough()`?

Comment: Hello Andrei, thanks.. I found the problem, I will answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the way to define the spy.
Reading [jasmine docs](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/jasmine.html) in jasmine.createSpyObject section I found how to create a spy correctly.

```js
const exampleSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ExampleSpy', {
        method1: Promise.resolve(true),
        method2: 'testResult'
});

const res = exampleSpy.method2();
expect(res).toBe('testResult');
```

The object may be like
`{key: returnValue }`

not like
`{key: ()=> returnValue}`